# Understanding the nature of #define

Tags: c

If I write something like

```
#define INT_PTR int*
INT_PTR ptr4, ptr5, ptr6;
```

In this case only ptr4 is pointer to an integer, rest of the values (ptr5 and ptr6) are integers. How they are taking the integer value ? Either it should give some compilation error.

Why is it this way that compiler is treating ptr5 and ptr6 as integers.

Comment: Macros are just text substitution. A typedef sounds closer to what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with the `#define`, which is simply a textual replacement.

After the preprocessor phase (when the substitution takes place), you end up with:

```
int* ptr4, ptr5, ptr6;
```

and, because the `*` binds to the *variable* rather than the *type,* you create one integer pointer and two integers.

This is why I prefer to write:

```
int *xyzzy;
```

rather than:

```
int* xyzzy;
```

since the former makes it clearer that the `*` belongs to the *variable.* If you want to define a new type in C, the command is, surprisingly enough, `typedef` :-)

```
typedef int * INTPTR;
INTPTR ptr4, ptr5, ptr6;
```

That defines a new type that will apply to all variables that follow it, rather than just substituting text, as per the macro. In other words, the type `INTPTR` (`int *`) applies to all three of `ptr4`, `ptr5` and `ptr6`.

Answer (score 11):

Because to declare pointer objects you would do:

```
int *ptr4, *ptr5, *ptr6;
```

In C, the token `*` does not belong to the type information, so you have to repeat it when you declare several objects. Note that this is a frequent mistake in C.

What you can do is to `typedef` instead:

```
typedef int * INTPTR;
```

Comment: Exactly. The * should be part of the variable, not of the type.

Comment: What you mean is that the `*` type construction operator is part of the individual declarator syntax, and not part of the common stem of declaration specifiers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code expands to

```
int* ptr4, ptr5, ptr6;
```

And since the asterisk (*) declaration is applied to only the identifier follwing it, it's natural that only ptr4 will actually be a pointer. (By the way, that's why it's conceptually wrong to write

```
int* ptr;
```

as you should indicate that the pointer declaration is only for one variable, as such:

```
int *ptr.
```

)

So, instead of a `#define` preprocessor directive (which is also wrong for type definitions), use the C `typedef` keyword:

```
typedef int *inptr;
intptr ptr4, ptr5, ptr6;
```